# jquery AJAX Unexpected token illegal

Tags: jquery

I have this code to fetch profile pictures and messages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=cinema&type=post";
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function(msg){
                 console.log( msg );
                 $.each( msg.data , function(i,obj){
                    var picUrl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + obj.from.id + '/picture';
                    console.log(picUrl);
                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       dataType: "jsonp",
                       url: picUrl,
                       success: function(pic){
                            $('#cinemas').append('<img src="' + pic + '"></img>' + obj.message + '<br />');
                       }
                });         

                 });
               }
             });
        });
```

But i am getting a "Unexpected token illegal" error in the Chrome console.

As far as i know, picUrl produces a valid URL.

Comment: Seems to be on the image itself?? profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/211648_1369191974_2463118_q.jpg:1

Comment: is that `:1` after .jpg really there? Doesn't look like a valid url.

Comment: It is, if you visit it in a browser, it displays a valid image, if you take the :1 off, the image still works! How can i get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the inner `$.ajax` is for...

Here's a demo of what I think you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Lobstrosity/vbDuu/

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using pic in your url but are you actually getting a url in your return function?

Comment: why would i use picUrl, this is the URl to grab profile pics from!

Comment: No, that's fine. pic is the parameter as passed to the success function by the AJAX handler.